Parse Rust into AST with / for use in Python
Usually it's the other way round, parsing Python with Rust, see here or here - in my case though I am looking for a way to parse Rust code with Python ideally into something like an AST that can be analyzed (ideally before any further compilation steps kick in). Specifically, I want to extract enum and struct definitions from an application written in Rust for unit-tests written in Python. Is there a standard way of doing this, perhaps through the Rust compiler?

You might want to check https://pypi.org/project/tree-sitter/

Thanks @mousetail'he-him' - this is what I was looking for.

Dependencies:
pip install tree-sitter tree-sitter-rust

Example usage:
import tree_sitter_rust as tsrust
from tree_sitter import Language, Parser

with open("some.rs", mode = "rb") as f:
    raw = f.read()

parser = Parser(Language(tsrust.language()))
tree = parser.parse(raw)

enums = [
    node
    for node in tree.root_node.children
    if node.type == 'enum_item'
]

print(enums)


I'd not run into Tree Sitter before. Looks to be very comprehensive. Thanks!
